# Set value to dropdown button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Bootstrap Dropdown but I just realize that is not doing what I want

```
<span class="dropdown" dropdown>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-white dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
      Click
      <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" dropdown-menu>
    <li ng-repeat="data in rotations.data">
      {{data.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

there is the html I am using, what I want is:

set initial value to the `<a>`, instead of `Click` which is the actual value. I need that the `<a>` contains the name of the first element in `data.name`, and then that value should change depending on the option that the user selects.

here is all I have in the controller

```
  function RotationsCtrl (Rotations, $scope, $rootScope, $state) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = Rotations;
  }
```

what do you recommend me to do ?

Comment: Probably a good place for a directive here where the state of the dropdown selection can be encapsulated in that directive. I would take a look at the source code for this https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown

Comment: @BillPull I am using that library, but it seems to do the same

Comment: which version of that library it looks like the current docs have some slightly different namespaces?

Comment: Why can't you just replace the hard-coded `Click` with `{{rotations[0].name}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set one more scope variable and initialize it on controller first

```
vm.selectedRotation = Rotations[0];
```

then put ng-click on li tag to change selected value

```
<li ng-repeat="data in rotations.data" ng-click="vm.selectedRotation = rotation;">
  {{data.name}}
</li>
```

and of course set that variable on button name

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-white dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
  {{vm.selectedRotation}}
  <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```